# SwifUI Xcode 12.5 iOS 14 Add UIImage to observed view model

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am using this tutorial as a reference.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/11609977-getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-and-swiftui

I am basically trying to add an image to a Card type in this tutorial.

In my app, AddStoryView gets 2 strings title & storyText and a UIImage from user input.

Trying to figure how to update the views in `ForEach` when the image gets edited.

In my model that I can’t figure how to use `UIImage` with Codable. So, I tried a different approach of uploading images separately. And calling onAppear with a method that gets the image for the story in the `StoryCardView`. It does work but when updating images it’s not updating until the app restarts.

```
 import Foundation
 import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

 struct Story: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var author: String?
    var headline :String?
    var bodyText: String?
    var userId: String?
    var storyId: String?
//  var storyImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "logo")!
    var comment: String?
}
```

Here is V`iewModel` that `StoriesListView` observes `storyViewModels` to render stories in view:

```
 import Foundation
 import Combine
 import PhotosUI

 class StoryListViewModel: ObservableObject  {
    
    @Published var storyRepository = StoryRepository()
    
    @Published var storyViewModels: [StoryViewModel] = []
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        storyRepository.$stories.map { stories in
            stories.map(StoryViewModel.init)
        }
        .assign(to: \.storyViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func addStory(story: Story, image: UIImage) {
        storyRepository.uploadStory(story: story, image: image)
        
    }   
}
```

Here is `StoryViewModel`:

```
    import Foundation
    import Combine

    class StoryViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    private let storyRepository = StoryRepository()
    @Published var story: Story
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var id = ""
    
    init(story: Story) {
        self.story = story
        
        // set up binding for story between the stories id and the viewmodels id then store object in cancellables so it can be canceled later
        $story
            .compactMap { $0.id }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func editStory(story: Story, image: UIImage) {
        storyRepository.updateStory(story, image)
    }
}
```

Here is Story Repository where communication is handled with Firebase:

```
    import FirebaseFirestore
    import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
    import FirebaseStorage
    import Combine
    import PhotosUI

    class StoryRepository: ObservableObject {
    ////
    private let path: String = "stories"
    private let store = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var stories: [Story] = []
    
    var userId = ""
    
    private let authenticationService = AuthService()
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        authenticationService.$user
            .compactMap { user in
                user?.uid
            }
            .assign(to: \.userId, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        authenticationService.$user
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.get()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func get(){
        store.collection(path)
            .addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting stories: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                let stories = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap {document in
                    try? document.data(as: Story.self)
                } ?? []
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.stories = stories
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here is `StoriesListVIew`:

```
  struct StoriesListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storyListVM: StoryListViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack (spacing: 20){
                ForEach(storyListVM.storyViewModels) { storyViewModel in
                    StoryCardView(storyViewModel: storyViewModel)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the whole story gets updated in `StoryRepository`:

```
 func updateStory(_ story: Story, _ image: UIImage) {
        guard let storyDocId = story.id else { return }
                    ImageManager.instance.uploadStoryImage(storyID: story.storyId ?? "", image: image) { (_ success: Bool) in

            if success {
                do {
                    try self.store.collection(self.path).document(storyDocId).setData(from: story)
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Unable to add card: \(error.localizedDescription).")
                }
              return
            } else {
                print("Error uploading post image to firebase")
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am getting the image to show in StoryCardView with `onAppear`:

```
 private func getStoryImage() {
        ImageManager.instance.downloadStoryImage(storyID: storyViewModel.story.storyId ?? "") { (returnedImage) in
            if let image = returnedImage {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.storyImg = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From reading your question, I'm having a hard time figuring out what the issue is. Are you asking how to upload the image? Or trying to figure out how to update a view? But, you don't `StoryCardView` shown... General advice: a `@Published` array of `ObservableObject`s won't work -- `@Published` works well with value types, not reference types. Also, in terms of uploading the image, you should not try to encode a `UIImage` into a Codable object and store it. Store a path to the file (eg a `String`) and upload the file to Firebase Storage separately from the model record.

Comment: I have the Image Just looking how to update the views in list when image gets edited. If you look at the tutorial I am just wanting to add an Image to their card. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Where in your code does it show the image getting edited?

Comment: I will add that code to question

Comment: So you want to update your UI when `updateStory` is called? But you don't seem to be updating anything in your local state -- it's just updating Firebase. What are you expecting to see change locally?

Comment: My updateStory method does update the story(strings) and it rerenders in the view. But the image is not up dating in the view until after the app is re loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232015/discussion-between-mike-haslam-and-jnpdx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I could not see the forrest thru the trees. What I learned from this is: 1 write better questions. 2 it was just a type thing, if I would have focused on the part in my question where I said I just want to add an image to the card type in the RW tutorial I may have found a solution sooner.

Note I am not getting the image by downloading in onAppear anymore it's all part of the model thanks to Combine and FirebaseFirestoreSwift as in the RW tutorial I referenced.

Here is my new model

```
struct Story: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var author: String?
    var headline :String?
    var bodyText: String?
    var userId: String?
    var storyId: String?
    var storyImage: Data?
    var comment: String?
    var createdAt: Date
}
```

I now just convert the UIImage to data after getting the image from user then add it to Story type.

```
 private func add() {
    let imageData = imgSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.01)
    let storyToAdd = Story(headline: title, bodyText: storyText, storyImage: 
    imageData,createdAt: Date())
    storyListVM.addStory(story: storyToAdd)
}
```

When my storyImage actually gets uploaded to firebase I convert it back to UIImage

```
func uploadStoryImage(storyID: String, image: Data, handler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()) {

    // convert image to UIImage can force unwrap because a default image is passed
    let image = UIImage(data: image)!
    // Get the path where we will save the image
    let path = getStoryImagePath(storyID: storyID)
  
    // Save image to path
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        self.uploadImage(path: path, image: image) { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(success)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

When image is rendered in view that is observed from view model it's of type data so needs to be converted to type UIImage. Note storyImg is a default UIImage in view

```
 Image(uiImage: UIImage(data:storyViewModel.story.storyImage!) ?? storyImg)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you. In general, images are usually stored in Firebase Storage and then a reference (ie path) to them is stored in Firestore. Firestore itself has caps you're likely to hit (I see that you're already using a highly compressed version of the image), but again, if this solution is working for you, that's good for now.

Comment: Thanks how would I store a path in firebase?

Comment: It would be a String value in your model that stores the relative path (like `user/images/profile123.png`) that you uploaded to Storage.

Comment: Thanks just trying wrap my head around how render the image in my view from that path or?

Comment: You would have to download it from Firebase Storage. The Firebase Storage documentation shows you how to download the data. You'd probably do this in an `ObservableObject` and then present the `Image` once it had been downloaded.

Comment: I am not doing it onAppear anymore its already in firestore as part of model I get this from Combine and FirebaseFirestoreSwift I never mention that in my question sorry that's all in the tutorial I referenced